# jQuery validation cannot call method

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, undefined

I am writing some code for form validation using the jquery.validate.js library.

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDefaults' of undefined validate.html:239
>   (anonymous function)

At this line of code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});
```

What does this error mean, and how can I get the code working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this means there is no object `$.validator`, probably are not loading the library correctly. Show the code where you include the library, you might be trying to load it before jquery is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chekc your jQuery  tag. The problem is exaclty what @Patrick Evans said, you're not loading the library correctly.

For reference:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That is only if the jQuery file is in the same folder as the page I'm loading it on.... Also, check your src... maybe your path is not correct...